# Mysqli Update Query is not working all though is showing no error too?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have been trying to update a row in mysql database so it is not updating and even not getting any mysqli error so if you can please have a look at my code that why it is not working..besides one column in the update process is unique so May be the query didn't workout as column is unique but it should give error then since it's not doing that too so that's why it seems like it's not working as :

```
if ($_POST['invoice_price']!=="0") {
$id = $_POST['id'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$formlink = $_POST['formlink'];
$invoice_price = $_POST['invoice_price'];

$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE clientlog SET Username='$username',Password='$password',formlink='$formlink',invoice_price='$invoice_price' WHERE ID=$id") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
```

It will be too kindful please if you workout the missing thing to me..!

Comment: can you post the html? or the form?

Comment: please post your form also. Maybe an issue from there also. Had you tried printing the values

Comment: @arunrc : I have been trying to check post values through Firebug so it seems to be correct..!

Comment: Try it in the page by commenting the query and echo the values.

Comment: Please do post the form.

Comment: add this `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, to make sure your code is running without any error, if it is then your html code is missing something..

Comment: It's really too complex let me post the whole form with php query..!

Comment: Warning: SQL injection vulnerabilities. Use Prepared statements

Comment: Thanks it was working fine..I just find out an extra function there..which was not in correct syntax..! so it started working after removing that..!

Comment: @DarylGill : Not really getting what are you trying to let me know..!

Comment: @SalmanKhan SQL Injection/Improperly formatted queries are something which developers face without even knowing (some of the time) It's a method used by malicious users to change your Query into something else & cause havock on your SQL Engine. http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php  Prepared statements make your input 100% safe as apposed to putting it directly into a `mysqli_query()` & Have a reference from XKCD: http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. I have just added the quote for id ('$id')

```
if ($_POST['invoice_price']!=="0") {
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $formlink = $_POST['formlink'];
 $invoice_price = $_POST['invoice_price'];

 $query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE clientlog SET Username='$username',Password='$password',formlink='$formlink',invoice_price='$invoice_price' WHERE ID='$id'") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
```